# Is it possible to beautify this JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have done my research but i cant find anything useful that are related to my question.

**Original JavaScript Code**

```
$("#furniture1").keyup(function(){
  samefunction();
});
$("#furniture2").keyup(function(){
  samefunction();
});
$("#furniture3").keyup(function(){
  samefunction();
});

$("#color1").keyup(function(){
  samefunction();
});
$("#color2").keyup(function(){
  samefunction();
});
$("#color3").keyup(function(){
  samefunction();
});
```

I can only come up with this solution, is there better solution?

```
var index_no = 0;

for(var i=1; i<=3; i++)
{
    index_no++;
    var name = '#furniture';
    name += index_no;

    $(name).keyup(function () {
        samefunction();
    });

    var name = '#color';
    name += index_no;

    $(name).keyup(function () {
        samefunction();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just separate selectors with `,`.

```
$("#furniture1, #furniture2, #furniture3, #color1, #color2, #color3").keyup(function(){
  samefunction();
});
```

Example

```js
$("#furniture1, #furniture2, #furniture3, #color1, #color2, #color3").keyup(function(){
    console.log(`Fired from the input ${this.id}`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="furniture1">
<input id="furniture2">
<input id="furniture3">
```

For dynamic you need a loop. You can just decrease the code written in the loop like

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
{
    $(`#furniture${i}, #color${i}`).keyup(function () {
        samefunction();
    });
}
```

Or as @Satpal have mentioned in the comments you can add a common class for all elements and use that class to bind the event handler like.

```js
$(".someClass").keyup(function(){
    console.log(`Fired from the input ${this.id}`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="furniture1" class='someClass'>
<input id="furniture2" class='someClass'>
<input id="furniture3" class='someClass'>
```

Comment: what if i have the index number to 24?

Comment: You will have dynamic indexes ?

Comment: @learnprogramming, Add a CSS common class then use class selector to bind event handler

Comment: @SurenSrapyan not dynamic...just curious what if the index number is greater than 10...would it be really messy if i put the name and followed by comma until it reaches 10

Comment: @learnprogramming Yes it will be messy. I have edited the answer. Please read again

Comment: @Satpal ermm i dont really understand, still learning in programming js...

Comment: @learnprogramming see [kumar_harsh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47387204/)

Comment: the edited answer is quite nice, i will use this for now...if i have time i will use the one @kumar_harsh does

Answer (score 3):

Option 1: Use event delegation. This solution is pure javascript:

```
document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('keyup-capturer')) {
    somefunction();
  }
});
```

---

#### Demo

```js
$ctr = document.getElementById('counter');
document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('keyup-capturer')) {
    somefunction();
  }
});
function somefunction() {
    console.log(`Fired from the input ${this.id}`);
    $ctr.innerHTML = parseInt($ctr.innerHTML, 10) + 1;
};
```

```html
<input id="furniture1" class="keyup-capturer">
<input id="furniture2" class="keyup-capturer">
<input id="furniture3" class="keyup-capturer">
<input id="color1" class="keyup-capturer">
<input id="color2" class="keyup-capturer">
<input id="color3" class="keyup-capturer">

<div>Key Ups: <span id="counter">0</span></div>
```

---

Option 2 <sup>[*]</sup>: If you do need to use jQuery, you can either use event delegation, or use a `class` for calling the same function on when keyup is captured in any element on that class:

```
$('.keyup-capturer').keyup(function() { samefunction(); });
```

And assign the `.keyup-capturer` class to all the `#furniture-x` and `#color-x` element IDs.
**I don't recommend this approach anymore. See the discussion below.**

---

<sup>[*] Some observations:</sup>

- <sup>Use [event
  delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) over
  class-based listeners for best results.</sup>
- <sup>Don't use for loops or `forEach` or `map` to attach event handlers. You'll just be adding a lot of event handlers, and eventually, you'll find your page growing slower with more complexity.</sup>
- <sup>Avoid attaching listeners to a **set** of selected elements (such as shown in Option #2). See [this line in jQuery's source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/3e902a812014e8a6980e08599c4840b1cb969f7c/src/event.js#L93). jQuery hides the implementation detail from you, but under the hoods, it still attaches one event listener per element. So, if you're using non-ID-based selectors such as class selectors `$('.c1')`, or attribute selectors `$('[disabled]')`, etc), keep in mind this fact. Thanks to @t.niese for [pointing this out](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1960455/t-niese) in the comments.</sup>

Comment: Why do you complain about the bad performance of a `map` or `forEach` in the other question and in this answer, while suggesting the same in yours? A `$(".keyup-capturer").keyup(...)` will also iterate over each matched element to attach an individual event listener to each of them.

Comment: Yes, it is. Use addEventListener

Comment: Using `$(".keyup-capturer").keyup(...)` will add the same amount of event handlers compared to a solution that uses `forEach` and `addEventListener`, the jQuery api just hides this from you.

Comment: I'm not recommending the `$classSelector.keyup` approach. I'm recommending the event-delegation approach.

Comment: At the time I wrote the comments you didn't recommend the event-delegation, and the answer was contradictory, now you have corrected most parts. The `[...]you can either use event delegation, or use a class for calling the same function on when keyup is captured in any element on that class[...]` in option 2 and the `Don't use for loops` is still misleading, because it indicates that using class and delegate events would be similar, but using classes will use a loop.

Comment: @t.niese actually, I had put the recommendation before your first comment came in (check the timestamps), but yeah, SO does not do auto-refresh sometimes, so it can seem all weird when answers are evolving quickly. At least we do agree on the approach ;-)

Comment: Plus, I didn't know about the implicit use of for-loop in jQuery for class-based selectors. Thanks for the info. Is there some documentation or reference for it, so that I may refer to it in my answer?

Comment: JS only allows to directly attache event handlers, therefore, jQuery is logically also limited to this.  The relevant part in the docs `[...]The .on() method attaches event handlers to the currently selected set of elements in the jQuery object[...]` and github [jquery/event.js](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/3e902a812014e8a6980e08599c4840b1cb969f7c/src/event.js#L93).  The `.on` will always add an event handler to every element in the jQuery result set on that it is called.

Answer (score 2):

try adding a class `furniture` on all furnitures, class `color` on all colors, and so on... so that you can select them by group:

```
let furnitures = document.querySelectorAll('.furnitures');
furnitures.forEach((furniture) => {
   furniture.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
      // your code here
   })
})
```

or you can pass your function directly:

```
let furnitures = document.querySelectorAll('.furnitures');
furnitures.forEach((furniture) => {
   furniture.addEventListener('keyup', samefunction)
})
```

Comment: ```furnitures.forEach((furniture) => {
   furniture.addEventListener('keyup', samefunction())
})```

Won't work because you'll be executing the handler and not binding it.  It should be 

```
let furnitures = document.querySelectorAll('.furnitures');
furnitures.forEach((furniture) => {
   furniture.addEventListener('keyup', samefunction)
})
```