# How to beautify/refactoring this JavaScript codes?

Tags: javascript

Previously I have questions asking about beautify js codes [in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47387137/is-it-possible-to-beautify-this-javascript-code), but this time i'm not sure how to beautify this code below because im using **words instead of index numbers.** (bolted words are the reason it is NOT SAME as my previous question)

**Original JS Code**

```
//food
$("#food_east").keyup(function () 
{
    samefunction();
});

$("#food_west").keyup(function () 
{
    samefunction();
});

$("#food_north").keyup(function () 
{
    samefunction();
});

$("#food_south").keyup(function () 
{
    samefunction();
});

//beverage
$("#beverage_east").keyup(function () 
{
    samefunction();
});

$("#beverage_west").keyup(function () 
{
    samefunction();
});

$("#beverage_north").keyup(function () 
{
    samefunction();
});

$("#beverage_south").keyup(function () 
{
    samefunction();
});
```

And this is only food and beverage, i have not include others such as candy, snacks etc because its too messy to dump all my codes here. I can only come up with this solution, is there better solution?

```
var compass = ["east", "west", "north", "south"];

    for(var i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        var name = "#food_";
        name += compass[i];

        $(name).keyup(function () {
            samefunction();
        });

        var name = "#beverage_";
        name += lokasi[i];

        $(name).keyup(function () {
            samefunction();
        });
    }
```

Comment: Couldn't you use a class on all elements in question? Then you would only have to select using that class and assign the event handler.

Comment: You should pass the function name (reference) into `keyup`. `keyup(samefunction)`

Comment: _"Beautifying"_ JavaScript does not mean what you think it means. It refers to formatting (whitespace, indentation, linebreaks...). Your case could be called _"refactoring"_.

Comment: @Sirko for example?

Comment: @anon it is my own question...it is DIFFERENT, pls refer to my edited question

Comment: @evolutionxbox for example?

Comment: inside samefunction() function have another some function which leads to each of these

Comment: I gave an example. Just in case, look at here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a class, instead of one unique identifier per element. A class is like a group name. All elements with that class can be selected at once.

```js
$(".someClass").keyup(function () {
    console.log("Keyup event!")
    // Do stuff
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="someClass" type="text" />
<input class="someClass" type="text" />
<input class="someClass" type="text" />
<input class="someClass" type="text" />
<input class="someClass" type="text" />
<input class="someClass" type="text" />
```

Answer (score 1):

This is why classes where invented... give every element that same class and bind the function to that class.

Another way could be to use the selector ‘starts with’: `$(‘[id^=“food_”]’).keyup...`

Comment: That's a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @patrick which means it automatically identify food_west, food_east, food_north and food_south?

Comment: Yes, but also food_blablabla, so everything that starts with ‘food_’

Comment: ‘Give every event that same class and bind the function’ is an answer, not a comment...